# Laravel varias pestañas

Tags: laravel

Buenas tardes. Tengo un problema. Les explico. mi problema es que ejecuto php artisan serve corre bien. pero consumo una api. el cual tarda como 3 horas en actualizar los datos. mientras tanto cuando abro otra pestaña no permite ejecutarlo hasta que termine el proceso de consumir la api y entonces puedo trabajar normal sobre laravel pero luego si ejecuto otra ves el api tengo que esperar otras 3 horas para poder verlo normal. entonces se me ocurrió abrirlo en otro navegador y tampoco primero tiene que termina el proceso y no me deja continuar espero su respuesta saludos

Answer (score 0):

Gracias ya busque la solución. para correrlo como servidor sin tener restricciones solo run con laragon, xammp en la carpeta public